# Rotating and Shifting image doesn't change FFT2

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

I have an image and its fourier transform.
When I rotate it, its fourier transform rotates too, but I can't figure it out. Why does this happen?
On the other hand, when I shift the image, its fourier transform doesn't change. As I know, time shifting means frequency shifting. Am Iwrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time shift corresponds to a **phase** shift in frequency domain, not a frequency shift. Since you display only the magnitude of the 2D FFT before and after the shift, you do not observe the phase shift.

$$f(x) \Rightarrow F(w) \\ f(x-a) \Rightarrow e^{-j2\pi wa} F(w)
$$

Rotation in space corresponds to a rotation in frequency domain as you observe.

For proofs, see these notes on [Some Properties of Fourier Transform](http://www.eee.hku.hk/~work8501/WWW2008/ho4.pdf)